# TrafficStats returning double the actual bytes

Tags: android, download, upload

I am comparing two methods to determine the downloaded bytes. One of them is TrafficStats, the other is reading the size of the received bytes directly. Somehow TrafficStats shows double the actual downloaded bytes for some devices. But is it not consistent. I think it might have to do with the version of the device as well.

Some of the affected Devices are:
Acer E380, 
Asus Nexus 7, 
FUJITSU F-01F, 
HTC Desire S, 
etc... I saw many more with this issue but the list would be too long and not helpful.

I am pretty sure that there is a but but I don't know what I can do about it. I am wondering if someone could think of a way to test if the device is affected without actually downloading or uploading a file. Currently about 1% of our users are affected by this bug.